# Why won't this cache?

Tags: http-headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 21:42:35 GMT
ETag: 28
Vary: *
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 21:42:24 GMT
Content-Length: 258
```

I am building the expiration date myself and setting it, yet it still won't cache.  I am using SqlDependency with this, but what I want for it to do is hold it in cache for say...30 minutes, then after 30 sql cache comes into play.

Comment: How are you testing whether it is cached?

Comment: dev tools in IE - network sniff tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that I notice is "Cache-Control: private". As long is it private it won't be cached by proxies and I'm not sure all the browsers will cache it.

Comment: this is right, the microsoft add on I was using had an attribute that was adding this by default.